# Java generics, get Class<T> of generic parameter

Tags: java, generics

I have an abstract class:

```
public abstract class RootProcessor<T> {
    Class<T> clazz;
}
```

I need to fill `ClassT clazz;` with the children of `RootProcessor` - every child has its own `T`

I found only one solution, but it needs compiler argument `-Xlint:unchecked`

```
public RootProcessor(){
    this.clazz = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}
```

Is this the best solution? Can we do the same without `-Xlint:unchecked` ?

Comment: Don't use `-Xlint:unchecked`, use `@SuppressWarnings` as locally as possible if you need unsafe casts.

Comment: And, yeah, there is no way to get `Class<T>` safely at runtime if the compiler can't track the type of `T` from beginning to end. The typesafe but boilerplatey approach here is to simply introduce a protected constructor that takes `clazz` as a parameter.

Comment: @millimoose: Why don't you write that as an answer? I have very little to add to your comments ;-)

Comment: yes, its a great answer. I think constructor with a parameter is a great solution. Its simple answer for this question )))

Comment: As an example: `key = gson.fromJson(json, key.getClass().getGenericSuperclass());` fixes `key = gson.fromJson(json,HashMap.class);`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The typesafe, but boilerplatey way to do this is to pass the `Class<T>` token "where the compiler can see it":

```
public abstract class RootProcessor<T> {
    Class<T> clazz;

    protected RootProcessor<T>(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }
}

public class FooProcessor extends RootProcessor<Foo> {
    public FooProcessor() {
        super(Foo.class);
    }
}
```

If you're doing an unchecked cast but you "know what you're doing" and want the compiler to stop complaining, the correct approach would be localising the non-type-safe-but-you-know-they-work bits and using `@SuppressWarnings`:

```
public abstract class RootProcessor<T> {
    Class<T> clazz;
    { initClazz(); }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void initClazz() {
        // the usual verbiage you already have in your question
        this.clazz = this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass().yadda().blah();
    }
}
```

(I won't hold this against you :P)

Answer (score 3):

There is a post of the same subject: [Reflecting generics](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=208860)

And a class that implement it:[TypeArgumentsUtils.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/de.alpharogroup/jaulp.lang/3.11.0/de/alpharogroup/lang/TypeArgumentsUtils.java)

An example is in the unit test.

So if you have this class:

```
public class BarProcessor extends RootProcessor<Bar> {
    public BarProcessor() {
    }
}
```

than you would get the first parameter with:

```
Class barClass = TypeArgumentsUtils.getFirstTypeArgument(
        RootProcessor.class, BarProcessor.class);
```

Comment: Second link is broken.

Comment: Is this the missing link: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/de.alpharogroup/jaulp.lang/3.11.0/de/alpharogroup/lang/TypeArgumentsUtils.java